# How to manage Vue components inside the module folder?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I am using [Caffeinated](https://caffeinatedpackages.com/guide/packages/modules.html#installation) package for modules.

Hi, I'm trying to use Vue JS components that are stored directly in a module Resources folder (/js/components).
I would rather not write for each Vue component its path in the main Laravel app.js file, so i'm thinking about editing the app.js files to scan Modules components folder and require each component automatically, but I'm not so good with the Vue JS enviroment.

Is there a simpler way to use Vue components inside modules folders?

Comment: Yes, that's a good way and its also explained in the [official vue docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Automatic-Global-Registration-of-Base-Components)

Comment: I checked above mentioned document @IlGala, But it's not possible in laravel modular structure.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I read your question too fast. Can't you publish the module assets? in this way you will have always the same directory (something like `resources/js/vendor/my_package`)